# I want to open a gnome-terminal, connect to SSH and then send commands

Tags: python, ssh

I am running on Ubuntu 18, and cannot upgrade and I have gnome-terminal.
I am new to Python programming, learning from scratch and I have a GUI.

I want:

1. To open a gnome terminal -> OK
2. With said terminal connect to SSH -> OK
3. Send a command(s), depending of necessity -> I need help here
   I don't know how to proceed. What I have so far, says that the pipe is broken, which i think is normal, since connecting to a SSH is basically switching to another pipe.

This is what I have so far:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
import subprocess, time, pexpect, datetime, os

class Application(Gtk.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self)

    def do_activate(self):
        window = Gtk.Window(application=self)
        window.set_title("My GUI Application")

        box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
        box.set_size_request(300, 200)
        button1 = Gtk.Button(label="Core logs")
        button1.connect("clicked", self.on_button1_clicked_CORE)
        box.pack_start(button1, True, True, 0)
        window.add(box)
        window.show_all()

    def on_button1_clicked_CORE(self, widget):
        command1 = "ssh-add '/home/ssh_key';ssh root@xxx.xx.x.xx"
        command2 = "ls"
        terminal = "gnome-terminal"
        process = subprocess.Popen([terminal, "--", "bash", "-c", f"{command1}; exec bash"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        time.sleep(3)  # Wait for 3 seconds
        #process.communicate(input=command2.encode())

app = Application()
exit_status = app.run(None)
```

I want and NEED for the terminal to be VISIBLE.

1. To open a gnome terminal -> OK
2. With said terminal connect to SSH -> OK
3. Send a command(s), depending of necessity -> I need help here

I don't know how to proceed. What I have so far, says that the pipe is broken, which i think is normal, since connecting to a SSH is basically switching to another pipe.

Comment: The desire to run commands in a new terminal is a common beginner request, but often misdirected. Just write a script which does the SSH parts and then you can run it in an existing terminal or launch it in a new one. Ultimately the purpose of automation is to get to the point where you don't need to see what's happening. For the remote commands, look at Paramiko.

Comment: @tripleee I understand your point of view, but I am trying to make a program in Ubuntu to take logs from a remote machine, and I want a visible window, in order to search in the logs. I will replicate this for each process that I want to log.

Comment: Unless you need to continue interacting with the remote host, simply run the command and display the results in a window of your own. `subprocess.run(['ssh', '-i', '/home/ssh_key', 'root@xxx.xx.x.xx', 'ls'], text=True).stdout`